# Network Operation And Screen Rotation

Tags: android, http, android-asynctask, rotation

I am trying to make an app that works on landscape and portrait. I have a login screen where a user can login through a webserver. So I want to show a progress bar showing 'Please wait.. until the httprequest is done'. The same time I want the app to be able to rotate without canceling the request. My question is how can I archive that and what to use? (AsyncTask, Service, IntentService), I read that async task is killed when screen is rotated.

```
<activity
    android:name=".ui.activity.MyActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
```

Comment: With async task you could place it in a fragment to retains its state -- you could also temporarily lock the screen -- check here -- https://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2013/05/10/dealing-with-asynctask-and-screen-orientation/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also place your login logic inside a fragment and call  setRetainInstance(boolean) when your fragment is created. This method helps fragment retain its instance across Activity re-creating(such as configuration changes and in your case screen rotation) according to https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setRetainInstance(boolean)